# jQuery plugin DataTables won't connect to database

Tags: jquery, sql, datatables

I've been working on this for some while now, so any advice is appreciated. I'm creating a table where users can enter their products and additional product information. I'm using the jQuery plugin called DataTables (https://datatables.net/). Everything *looks* right, however it's like the data listed isn't connected to the plugin. You can't sort anything or search anything. As a matter of a fact, it says that it's showing zero of zero entries. Here's what it looks like:

[image: Screen shot of DataTables plugin]

Here's all of my code:

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once("db.php");

$sql_prod = "SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id ASC";
$results = mysqli_query($db,$sql_prod) or die(mysqli_error());
$product = "";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<div class="container">
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
          <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
          <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script src="jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">     
            $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#products_table').DataTable();
            });
        </script>  
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <table id="products_table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Product Name</th>
                        <th>Product Description</th>
                        <th>Tax free price</th>
                        <th>Costs</th>
                        <th>Sales margin</th>
                        <th>Sales %</th>
                        <th>Edit</th>
                        <th>Delete</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                    if (mysqli_num_rows($results)>0) {
                        while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)){
                            $id = $row['id'];
                            $prodName = $row['prodName'];
                            $prodDesc = $row['prodDesc'];
                            $taxFree = $row['taxFree'];
                            $prodCost = $row['prodCost'];
                            $salesMargin = $row['salesMargin'];
                            $salesPercent = $row['salesPercent'];

                        $product .="
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td>$prodName</td>
                                    <td>$prodDesc</td>
                                    <td>$taxFree</td>
                                    <td>$prodCost</td>
                                    <td>$salesMargin</td>
                                    <td>$salesPercent</td>
                                    <td><a href='#'>Edit</a></td>
                                    <td><a href='#'>Delete</a></td>                         
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>";                      
                        }
                            echo $product;                  
                    }
                    ?>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>  
    </body>
    </html>
    </div>
```

Any suggestions, even crazy ones, I'll try. Many thanks!

Comment: Your `tbody`, must be outside the block while